# How can I disable Windows Server's prompting for shutdown reasons every time I shut down on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm not using this as a production server but rather as a development box, and not being able to shut the thing down without entering stuff into the reason box is annoying. Can I disable that behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Type gpedit.msc in RUN dialog box and press Enter.
2. It'll open Group Policy Editor. Now go to:

   Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System
3. In right-side pane, look for "Display Shutdown Event Tracker" option.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. (Will accept in 2 mins)

Comment: No Problem glad to help.